# is Nested queries on DynamoDB efficient?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

One of my developer team member is using LSI(Local secondary index) functions on DynamoDB to fetch a specific row.
Two or Three nested queries are executed each.
On RDB, we used to make this as a single query... It seems not efficient.. isn't it? 
Is it normal and I/O execute time is efficient on DynamoDB?
I wonder we are using dynamoDB correctly,,that
To fetch a row, using multiple queries before to get LSI or GSI...

Comment: What’s your metric for efficiency? It’s hard to tell you which is more efficient when we don’t have a clear measurement of efficiency. It would also make it easier to provide help if you could include more information about your data model and current table schema.

Comment: there are several LSI and GSI in a table. and the goal of Query is similar to RDB, which has where by statement.

Comment: To get the a row, we added a another id filed and several queries (2 or 3) are executed. as the I/O time is getting higher then it degrade performance, doesn't it? if the final data as a query result is multiple rows then I understand we can use GSI. but to get only single row, I think it is over spec.... and length of each data is very short. (not a document)
Don't you think this is over-spec and fit-able for RDB?

Comment: You can use DynamoDB for pretty much anything, but it requires knowing your query patterns ahead of time so you can model your data the right way. If you don’t need the scalability and availability of DynamoDB, and you want to be able to run large number of different queries, then you probably would find a SQL database to be much more efficient. If you need the scalability that DynamoDB provides, then you should consider DynamoDB with either CloudSearch or ElasticSearch for queries.

Comment: I can’t really be any more specific without knowing your table structure and the queries you’re executing.